# Can't reach AJAX success event

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

Can't reach AJAX success event with any visible error (error event doesn't trigger either). I'm trying to load data to `<div id="list"></div>` block. After opening the page there's only 1 message in the console: `beforeSend` and no information about success or error events. How can I trigger success event and fill this  block?

views.py:

```
def load_api(request):
    return render(request, 'bboard/api_rubrics.html')

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_api_rubrics(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
        serializer = RubricSerializer(rubrics, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('all_api_rubrics/', load_api),
    path('all_api_rubrics/api/rubrics/', get_api_rubrics),
    ]
```

serializers.py:

```
class RubricSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Rubric
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'order')
```

models.py:

```
class Rubric(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_index=True,
        verbose_name='Name')
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Rubrics'
        verbose_name = 'Rubric'
        ordering = ['order', 'name']
```

api_rubrics.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>List of rubrics</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="list"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="{% static 'bboard/rubrics1.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

rubrics1.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/rubrics',
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log('beforeSend');
        },
        succsess: function(result) {
            update_table(result);
            console.log('after send');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
}

function update_table(data) {
    console.log('inside update_table');
    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    var s = '<ul>';
    for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        s += '<li>' + jsonData[i].name + '</li>';
    }
    s += '</ul>'
    list.innerHTML = s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think spelling of success may be the error. Can you check it with the right spelling.

```
success: function(result) {
           }
```

Comment: Oh gosh, I spent almost a day to understand where the mistake could have been... Thank You kindly! Now I got the error event and successfully corrected it.